# OpenVPN connect on startup

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I've set up OpenVPN to connect to my vpn service.  It works great.  Now, I need it to connect automatically.

I can run from a terminal

```
nmcli con up uuid 334464e5-5d0d-40f3-a4db-d41ca7e2929d
```

and it works great.

I'd like to make it connect when the system starts.  I added that command as a startup program, but still doesn't connect.

I edited /etc/default/openvpn as well.  I added this line:

AUTOSTART="VYPRVPN"

Still no joy.

From the logs:

```
Jan  2 23:11:19 ubuntu12-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1023]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 2241
Jan  2 23:11:19 ubuntu12-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1023]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Jan  2 23:11:19 ubuntu12-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1023]: <error> [1388725879.294774] [nm-vpn-connection.c:934] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
Jan  2 23:11:24 ubuntu12-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1023]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

VPN Secrets?  Help?

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your VPN connection through the GUI the password is saved in the key-ring. If you save your password in the connection file, like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyConnectionExampleName

in this file:

    # 1 here means key-ring I  think, but with 0, the password below is  used
    password-flags=0 

    [vpn-secrets]
    password=my_secret_password
```

Answer (score 0):

As the log has shown, it has tried to connect at startup and failed. It seems that your secret is stored in an authentication agent, which maybe starts later than OpenVPN. NetworkManager uses authentication agent provided by X session, but it starts very late.

You may find "Store connection secrets" in NetworkManager settings, choose "In a file" instead of "In secure storage", so that OpenVPN could find the secret by itself.